# ClassCastException that shouldn't happen

Tags: java, android, class, classcastexception

Im getting a ClassCastException that shouldnt be happening.
Here is the code:

```
TwitterApplication ta = (TwitterApplication)getApplication();
    OAuthProvider p = ta.getProvider();
```

As you see im trying to cast TwitterApplication from an Application.

```
public class TwitterApplication extends Application {

private Twitter twitter;

public Twitter getTwitter(){
    return this.twitter;
}

public void setTwitter(Twitter t){
    this.twitter = t;
}

private OAuthProvider provider;
private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;

public void setProvider(OAuthProvider oap){
    this.provider = oap;
}

public OAuthProvider getProvider(){
    return this.provider;
}

public void setConsumer(CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer c){
    this.consumer = c;
}

public CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer getConsumer(){
    return this.consumer;
}
```

As you see here, it extends application.

Is my casting knowledge faulty?
Why am I getting this error?
Thanks

EDIT:
Full Stacktrace:

```
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.laytproducts.IN/com.laytproducts.IN.TwitterUpdate}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at com.laytproducts.IN.TwitterUpdate.getConsumerProvider(TwitterUpdate.java:148)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at com.laytproducts.IN.TwitterUpdate.onCreate(TwitterUpdate.java:117)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
03-03 15:45:09.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3192):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainAct"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main" />

    <activity android:name=".FBUpdate">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.laytproducts.IN.WidgetAct.ACTION_WIDGET_FB" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TwitterUpdate">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.laytproducts.IN.WidgetAct.ACTION_WIDGET_TWITTER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <application android:name="TwitterApplication" />

    <receiver android:name=".WidgetAct">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/winfo"/>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: What does `getApplication` return?

Comment: getApplication returns an Application.

Ill post full in an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get an error if the concrete class returned by getApplication() is not actually a TwitterApplication object.

Have you amended your Android manifest file so that it uses this TwitterApplication class? If not, you will need to do. Simply extending Application is not enough - you must tell Android to use the TwitterApplication concrete class.

Comment: How would I do so? I have never worked with Applications before.

Comment: Nevermind. Found out. had to put INTO the <application> thingy. not make a new one. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest file, make sure you have:

```
<application android:name="TwitterApplication">
```

Comment: Didn't work. You can check my Edit to see my full manifest (or mostly full).

Comment: Of course, you need to edit the existing `application` tag, not create a new one.

Comment: Ya found that out soon after I posted that comment XD