# ClassCastException error Twitter4J in android

Tags: java, android, twitter4j, classcastexception

I'm using the Twitter4J [link](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library and is working well, the problem is not to receive the error java.lang.ClassCastException I had to declare my manifesto on the seguite:

```
<application> android:name=".TwitterApplication" </application>
```

after I did that the API works perfectly, but build other classes that have nothing to do with the the Twitter4J API and am having problems with the application context I believe.

if I call the method `finish();` inside another class, nothing happens, any button does not respond, and if I fill more than 3 textViews with some text I get the error below:
(That's certainly why I made that clear in auteração)

How can I get around this!

```
 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
 {com.app.player / twitter.DetailsTweet}:
 java.lang.ClassCastException: twitter4j.UserJSONImpl 01-11
 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:
 1650) 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:
 1666) 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access $ 1500 (ActivityThread.java: 117)
 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 android.app.ActivityThread $ H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:
 931) 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java: 99) 01-11
 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at android.os.Looper.loop
 (Looper.java: 130) 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java: 3689) 01-11
 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method) 01-11
 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java: 507) 01-11 03:32:20.629:
 E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit $
 MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java: 875) 01-11 03:32:20.629: E /
 AndroidRuntime (16968): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
 (ZygoteInit.java: 633) 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968):
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method) 01-11 03:32:20.629:
 E / AndroidRuntime (16968): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
 twitter4j.UserJSONImpl 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968):
 at twitter.DetailsTweet.initObjects (DetailsTweet.java: 69) 01-11
 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 twitter.DetailsTweet.onCreate (DetailsTweet.java: 40) 01-11
 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime (16968): at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
 (Instrumentation.java: 1047) 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime
 (16968): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
 (ActivityThread.java: 1614) 01-11 03:32:20.629: E / AndroidRuntime
 (16968): ... 11 more
```

Comment: have you defined activity in manifest ?

Comment: I know its not a problem in logcat but just remove space between ". TwitterApplication"

Comment: juned but the Activity is declared in the manifest

Comment: Shreya Shah: Spaces are because of tratutor but already corrected in post

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
<application> android:name=".TwitterApplication" </application>
```

with this one

```
<application> <activity android:name=".TwitterApplication"></activity> </application>
```

Comment: if I do it again I get the ClassCastException Twitter4J, a look at this post, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550745/classcastexception-that-shouldnt-happen&usg=ALkJrhjhzox6rkvulPbr6MCLC_lKhQZXGQ) I correct the error quoted him, however I lose the context of the application, in all the activitys will receive the context of TwitterApplication

Comment: read this post before all [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550745/classcastexception-that-shouldnt-happen&usg=ALkJrhjhzox6rkvulPbr6MCLC_lKhQZXGQ) I had the same problem, I decided to answer it cited, however if I start another activity (correctly declared in the manifest) and change the text of only 2 textViews everything is normal, but if for more than 3 get the error that is in the post .. If I call the method finish (); activity is not closed, it is as if the context of the class responded by TwitterApplication understood now?

Comment: My project is very extensive, I will try to solve here if you can not do a sample project and post here